# "Reminder: is waiting to hear from you - Stack Overflow Careers"

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, email

The "reminder"* email from Stack Overflow Careers has a couple of mis-formattings around the name of the company that sent the message you're reminding me about:

> [image]

1. The subject completely omits the name of the company.
2. The opening line has `****` there in place of the company.

<sup>*: Yes, I feel bad for requiring a reminder email in the first place... please forgive me :(.</sup>

Comment: What if the company is called "Reminder:" and the name of the recruiter is ****?

Comment: @BoltClock: Then I will eat my collection of Stack Overflow stickers, upload the video to YouTube, and post a link to it here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can happen if you've been messaged by an employer who hasn't filled in their company name.

The company name is supposed to go before the words "is waiting for you" in the subject, and where those asterisks are in the body. (The template is `**$CompanyName$**` so it's supposed to show the company name in bold - but if we don't have a company name then you get four asterisks as that doesn't get picked up by Markdown).

I've now updated this to be a little less stupid. If we don't have a company name, we'll now fill in the name of the person that messaged you instead.